# System of ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the system of differential equations
dx/dt = (y-x)/(x+y), dy/dt = -y/(x+y), where x and y are functions of t, and x(0)=0, y(0)=c (positive constant).  I would like to find x and y explicitly in terms of t.

This problem is related to my previous question "Probability problem with solution involving e."

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing Michael's answer:  Solve $dy/dx = y/(x-y), y(0)=c$ to get (in terms of the Lambert W function) $y(x) = \operatorname{e} ^{W(-x/c) + \mathrm{log} (c)}$.  Substitute this into the original equations to get a single equation:
$$
\frac{d x (t)}{d t} = \frac{\operatorname{e} ^{\Bigl(W \Bigl(-\frac{x (t)}{c}\Bigr) + \operatorname{log} (c)\Bigr)} - x (t)}{\operatorname{e} ^{\Bigl(W \Bigl(-\frac{x (t)}{c}\Bigr) + \operatorname{ln} (c)\Bigr)} + x (t)}
$$
$x(0)=0$.  Maple finds two solutions for this

**added**

The one that seems to work for real $c > 0$ is:
$$x(t) =
-\left(W_{-1} \left(\frac{-(-t + 2 c) \operatorname{e} ^{-2}}{c}\right) + 2\right)  \operatorname{e} ^{\Biggl(tW_{-1} \Biggl(\frac{-(-t + 2 c) \operatorname{e} ^{-2}}{c}\Biggr) + 2\Biggr)} c
$$

Comment: The $t$ in the exponent is likely a typo.

Comment: Yes, LambertW from Maple shortened to W for this, but the t was missed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be easier the other way round: solve $dx(y)/dy=x(y)/y-1$, $x(c)=0$ to get $x(y)=(\log c-\log y)y$. Then we are left with
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=-\frac1{\log c+1-\log y(t)}=\frac1{\log(y(t)/ec)}.$$
This is solved by $y(t)=\frac{t+d}{W((t+d)/ce^2)}$. Plugging in $y(0)=c$ gives $d=-2c$ for the lower branch of $W$, hence, barring mistakes,
\begin{align}
y(t)&=\frac{t-2c}{W_{-1}\left(\frac{t-2c}{ce^2}\right)},\\\\\\\\
x(t)&=2(c-y(t))-t,
\end{align}
for $-c(e-2)< t< 2c$. Note that $\lim_{t\to2c-}(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$ and $\lim_{t\to(2-e)c+}(x(t),y(t))=(-ce,ce)$.

Comment: From this we get
$$
\operatorname{e} ^{\Biggl(W_{-1} \Biggl(\frac{-(-t + 2 c) \operatorname{e} ^{-2}}{c}\Biggr) + 2\Biggr)} c
$$
which seems to agree with my solution below $t=1$.  Maybe we have different branches above $t=1$ or something.

Comment: Actually the place where the two solutions differ is where $x$ switches from increasing to decreasing.  My version of $y(t)$ has a corner there, yours doesn't.  So perhaps I should switch to a different branch of $W$ there.

Answer (score 0):

$$dx/dy=x/y-1.$$
From this, you find
$$\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{x}{y})=-\frac{1}{y}.$$

Comment: I understand what you did.  I wonder if there is a way to solve for x and y explicity in terms of t.